# Creating tooltips for each field in Sharepoint form

Tags: sharepoint, popup, sharepoint-designer, tooltip, field-description

I want to create tool tips for each part in a form which employees have to fill in a share point web page. When users move the mouse cursor on each field (Title, description, department etc.) the related tip will be automatically became visible as a simple pop-up (tool tip) and summarize what they should write there. and when the mouse cursor is not on one of these fields there is no tool tip.

How can I design such a system via share point designer? I am not able use any add ons. I can't upload any additional things to the server. I have to make page based design.

I would be glad if you kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using field description?
This is SharePoint's default way of adding additional information to fields.

[image: field description]

Comment: I have already used this but my boss prefers pop up solution.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the ToolTip control in my SharePoint Designer 2007 Toolbox, so I looked on W3Schools.com for a standard HTML option and found that you can use the <ABBR> tag.
See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_abbr.asp for the reference, but here's an example of a tooltip implemented on a SharePoint field title in a display form:

```
    <td valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" style="width: 50px">
       <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <nobr><abbr title="The actual number of man-days effort expended.">Man-days (Actual)</abbr></nobr>
       </H3>
    </td>
```

Comment: Can someone clarify how to do this? I am trying to add expanded tooltips to a form that adds information to a custom list. However, I cannot get access to the HTML for the form.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the aspx page for the form in SharePoint designer.  Then you can use SharePoint designer just like Visual Studio to see the code.  Try adding the "tooltip" attribute to the field controls within the form.  There is a small possibility these controls will actually be written using XSLT instead of ASP, so be prepared to do some studying.

Answer (score 0):

By default the display name of the site column becomes the tool tip for that field.